# Could only flying creatures exist on my planet?

Tags: evolution

I want to create a speculative evolution project about a planet called Icarus. Basically, it is roughly equal in size to Earth, but has 80% of its gravity, and an atmosphere 50% denser. What I’m wondering is, can I have the majority of animals fly?

Comment: Of course. Evolution is weird... it doesn't have a plan. There's no reason for it to produce 95% of its organism to dwell on land or in water, that just happened to be what we have on our planet due to its essentially random nature. If flight were a sufficient advantage (say predators had an edge over everything else), then flightless organisms might be wiped out to extinction while also keeping pressure on flight capable species to not lose that trait.

Comment: Your title and body don't match each other. Your title says *only* but your body says a *majority*. There's a big difference. *Majority* is a lot easier, but *only* seems unlikely since it leaves open an ecological niche that for some reasons remains unoccupied.

Comment: @JohnO I disagree. Things tend to be wiped to extinction because their ecological niche disappears or something else out competes them in the same niche. For an ecological niche just to be wiped clean and nothing else to fill it seems unlikely...and since the niches here are water and/or land...those aren't going to disappear unless the planet becomes a gas giant or vanishes.

Comment: Things can be wiped to extinction for any number of reasons. That the majority are from niches disappearing on Earth doesn't mean that this is some universal thing. If the niche is bad (flight's cheaper on this planet) and the branches of flightless life is small, there's no reason it might not be wiped out due to freak chance.

Comment: flying consumes a lot of energy, some prefer to burrow undergtound and by some I mean the majority hee hee. ;D

Comment: The problem with having ONLY flying creatures is that you leave a lot of unexploited ecological niches.  Consider that from flying birds you get flightless ones like the ostrich & kiwi, swimming ones like penguins, and ones like quail that spend most of their lives on the ground, only flying in short bursts to escape predators.

Answer (score 5):

**Sure!**

Of course you can!  In our ocean a majority of animals float because the density of water lends itself to that.  Floating with motive power could be flying.

Scifi flying-life worlds are common and cool.  Often you will find these set in the habitable layer of a gas giant, because the other option is falling.  I love those gas giant ones because different layers can be different ecosystems grading into each other.  If there is terra firms on your world, maybe there is some reason your flying life cannot touch down.  Some sort of life form, I hope.

The only caveat: denizens of Icarus must be referred to as "Iccys".

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by “majority of animals.” If you mean that the majority of *species* fly, it seems plausible. But if you want the majority of biomass to be airborne at all times, prospects seem doubtful.

First of all, if there is *any* solid ground on your planet at all, then *something* will live on it, simply because evolution tends to fill all available environmental niches with animals that are specialized for them. There are several reasons why solid ground is an appealing niche that can support lots of animal life:

- If you’re resting on the ground, you don’t need to be expending any energy. This saves lots of valuable calories.
- The ground tends to host more hiding places. Also, if you go to sleep in the air rather than on solid ground, you might float away to some different (and potentially dangerous) place without realizing it.
- Lifeless biomass and nutrients fall to the ground. When plants drop their leaves, nuts, and fruit, or when predators drop their leftovers, they end up on the ground. This is true of the seafloor as well, which is why the [benthos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benthos#Food_sources) niche exists.

If you want there to be few or no creatures living on the ground, there needs to be a good reason why the ground isn’t habitable. Otherwise something would have evolved to live there. Here are some possible reasons:

- There is no ground, because your planet is a gas giant.
- The atmosphere contains lots of dense toxic gas, which, being heavier than other atmospheric gases, is more abundant near the ground.
- There are lots of volcanoes on the ground, and “the floor is lava.”
- Creatures previously lived on the ground, but then something happened causing all terrestrial animals to go extinct and airborne animals to thrive, rendering the ground uninhabitable.
- The atmosphere is “foggy” and dense, so very little light reaches the ground and photosynthesis can only take place in the upper layers of the atmosphere.

Comment: Perhaps they encountered the [Shoe Event Horizon](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Shoe_Event_Horizon).

Comment: If you are considering just species, consider that there are 9-10 thousand bird species on Earth, but only about 6400 species of mammals.  Of course some mammals fly, and some birds don't :-)

Comment: @jamesqf True, but mammals are not the only land animals. What about reptiles? Amphibians? Insects? Arachnids? Even microbes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. Your planet's conditions already make it easier for animals to develop flight, so there wouln be as many adaptations necessary. For instance, maybe most animals don't need to be as lightweight so as to need hollow bones to be able to fly.

There are two ways I can see it happening. Either life develops closely tied to flight or life develops closer to what we would expect (in water) but flightless creatures are strongly selected against, perhaps especially affected by a mass extinction event.

For hypothesis one, we look at the conditions of old Earth that sparked life, wikipedia tells us it requires "an atmosphere of water, methane, ammonia and hydrogen". Now I'm not a biologist but maybe your denser atmosphere can lead to life happening in the air instead of in water first. This means your first bacteria would be aerial, leading to aerial multicelular beings, leading to the first aerial animals. I envision these as sort of light, flying jellyfish. Of course plant life would be developed at some point too, probably before a lot of this.

But I'm not sure of the viability of all that. So, on to hypothesis two. Life develops normally, originating in water, then leading to land animals and then some of these take flight. However, at some point it becomes increasingly hard to survive as a flightless creature. Perhaps geological activity leads to oceans overheating so marine fauna isn't as abundant. Or toxic gasses are released from the ground periodically with little warning. These  gasses are heavy and stay near the ground, so anything capable of rising above 20-40 meters for a period of time is safe. Or geysers could randomply erupt, throwing animals hundreds of meters above the ground (gliding would make the fall survivable also if you want to keep that as an option).